# Что такое RESTFULL?

Tags: api

Что такое RESTFULL?
Что такое REST API? 
Какие есть аналоги?

Comment: Rest - это реализация того, каким изначально задумывался http) Вопрос слишком общий, чтобы на него можно было дать лаконичный ответ.